# In CSS, is there any difference between *:link and :link?

Tags: css, user-interface, firefox, browser, css-selectors

In CSS, is there any difference between:

```
:link { color: green !important; }
:visited { color: blue !important; }
```

*and*

```
*:link { color: green !important; }
*:visited { color: blue !important; }
```

If it matters, the web browser is Firefox.

Comment: @temani-afif Thank you for pointing me to an existing excellent answer.  Given that the selectors used in that question (and answer) are different, how did you find it so fast?

Comment: I have answered that question :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif LOL.  I just noticed that!  Great answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just to make sure, does your answer also apply to the somewhat unique `:root`?

Comment: yes, if you check the Spec you can read: *is not the only component of a sequence of simple selectors ... then the * may be omitted*. So if you have any kind of selector and you are using `*` at the start, you can remove it. It apply to ID, classes, pseudo element; multiple classes, etc. In other words, `*` is only useful alone or when dealing with namespaces: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#univnmsp

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you! And, as your answer to the other question points out, it can also be useful for code clarity.